# Work with pointer to character and write the function to separate text words

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I would like to write a function that would take a pointer to char and a int (scan start index) as input, and return the first word after it. What is the problem with this code? No word returns.
The problem from where to include one of the separator characters is created. To scribble characters.

```
char *setWord(char string[], int *n) {
    char word[20] = "\0";
    string += *n;
    while (*string == ','||*string == '\t' || *string == '\n'
    || *string == ' '|| *string == '.' || *string == '!' || *string == '?') {
        string++;
       (*n)++;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (*string != ',' && *string != '\t'
                     && *string != '\n' && *string != ' ' &&
                     *string != '.' && *string != '!' &&
                     *string != '?') {
        word[i] = *string;
        string++;
        (*n)++;
        i++;
    }
    char *words = word;


    return words;
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data & expected results.

Comment: You have UB. `char *words = word; return words;` but `word[20]` is local variable.

Comment: Also, what if `n > strlen(string)`? Or if `string` is only `"    "`? Lots of issues in here.

Comment: Also, you have `n++` in the first while loop, but it should be `(*n)++`

Comment: Because I couldn't change a pointer to the character, I used the array, and then got it as a pointer. What is there other solution for doing this?@ChrisMM

Comment: You're using C++, I assume? Not C? Use `std::string`

Comment: Yes, but for some reason obliged myself write this function with the same input and output @ChrisMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you have UB since you return a pointer to a local variable (`words`). Originally you also had `n++` in your loop, instead of `(n*)++`, which is also UB. You need error checking in your code, but the following works, and still sticks with `char*` (no error checking):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

char *setWord( char string[], int *n ) {
    char word[20] = { 0 };
    string += *n;
    while ( *string == ',' || *string == '\t' || *string == '\n' || *string == ' ' || *string == '.' || *string == '!' || *string == '?' ) {
        string++;
        ( *n )++;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while ( *string != ',' && *string != '\t' && *string != '\n' && *string != ' ' && *string != '.' && *string != '!' && *string != '?' ) {
        word[i++] += *string;
        string++;
        ( *n )++;
    }

    std::cout << word;
    char *words = new char[i + 1];
    strncpy( words, word, I + 1 );

    return words;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "hello world!";
    int n = 5;
    char *word = setWord( str, &n );

    delete[] word;

    return 0;
}
```

Using `std::string`, you can do (no error checking):

```
std::string setWord( std::string string, int *n ) { // copy on purpose
    int start = *n;
    *n = string.length();
    size_t end = string.find_last_of( ",\t\n .!?" );
    string = string.substr( string.find_first_not_of( ",\t\n .!?", start ) );
    if ( end != std::string::npos ) {
        string = string.substr( 0, string.find_last_of( ",\t\n .!?" ) ); // because it's not end
        *n = (int)end;
    }
    std::cout << string;
    return string;
}
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta, my bad. I normally take out the `getchar()` before posting

Comment: Much better... and +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want to return a C string ([pointer to a] null terminated char array) from a function. The problem is that arrays are not first class objects in C, so you can only pass and return pointers. And any automatic array will reach its end of life at the end of the block in which it is declared. So if you nicely build your word into an automatic array and returns a pointer to it, what your current code does, the array is destroyed when the function returns only leaving a *dangling* pointer.

There are 2 possible ways, each with its pros and cons:

1. use allocated memory (@ChrisMM's answer).

   It can be recursive and thread safe. Simply you must document that the caller will be responsable for freeing the memory block, and how it should be done: `free` if you used `malloc`, `delete[]` if you used `new[]`.
2. use static memory

   A quick fix is to write:

   ```
   static char word[20];
   ```

   A static array will last until the end of the program so you can safely use it in the caller and no cleanup is required. But in a multi-threaded program, the static array will be shared among all the threads, to you must ensure that only one thread uses it at the same time and that another thread has not change it when you want to use it. Long story short: do not use that if the function is expected to be used in a multi-threaded program.